# What are Hermione's parents' real names?

Tags: harry-potter

So, we know they're dentists and that their aliases (after Hermione modifies their memories) are Wendell and Monica Wilkins.

But have their real names ever been divulged? If yes, what are they?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

JKR deliberately kept Hermione's family in the background as much as she could, since they weren't very interesting to the story.

> Does Hermione have any brothers or sisters?
>
> No, she doesn’t. When I first made up Hermione I gave her a younger sister, but she was very hard to work in. The younger sister was not supposed to go to Hogwarts. She was supposed to remain a Muggle. It was a sideline that didn’t work very well and it did not have a big place in the story. I have deliberately kept Hermione’s family in the background. You see so much of Ron’s family so I thought that I would keep Hermione’s family, by contrast, quite ordinary. They are dentists, as you know. They are a bit bemused by their odd daughter but quite proud of her all the same.
>
> – from [interview with J K Rowling at the Edinburgh Book Festival, 2004-09](http://web.archive.org/web/20120204062102/http://www.jkrowling.com/textonly/en/news_view.cfm?id=80)

As such, it makes sense not to give them any names beyond their surname, since it was not considered an important detail.

Comment: So Mr. and Mrs. Granger it is!

Comment: @DylanYaga Technically it's Dr. Granger for both of them. After all, they are both in possession of a Medical Doctorate, without which they wouldn't be allowed to practice dentistry.

Comment: @G.Vegt Actually in the UK most dentists don't use the title Dr, and its not clear if they are allowed to.

Comment: @Nick Interesting, didn't know that. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @G.Vegt It's the same for Vets, they don't get called Dr in the UK unless they have a PhD.

Comment: Hmmm..Well,it certainly IS disappointing to have a loose end. But since it doesn't affect the plot as such, I suppose it's fine. Personally, I would have loved just a line like "They're no longer Ned and Emily Granger (just saying :D ). As far as they're concerned,they're now Wendell and Monica Wilkins"..You know..for completeness' sake.
More to the point, this answer suffices. Thank you @G.Vegt :)

Comment: Clearly there has to be some fanfiction out there depicting the little sister of Hermione Granger that never was - I can only imagine her being either really excited to have a magical sister, or else intensely jealous of her for being magical and not 'sharing it' with her little sis.

Comment: The concept of Hermione's Muggle sister reminds me of Lily and Petunia Evans.

Answer (score -3):

They are just Dr. Granger for both of them. This is because they both possess a medical degree, and if they did not possess this degree they would prohibited against dental work.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of what their actual names were. The answer box is only meant for answering the question, not commenting on other people's answers. You'll be able to use the comment function if and when you earn a bit more [reputation](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @LogicDictates Technically, it does answer what the names are: Dr. Granger. It's the same as the accepted answer, except that it specifies the correct title (though it does not cite any source).

Comment: @Null - Most practicing dentists in the UK don't go by "Doctor".

Comment: @Valorum Wrong answers are still answers.

Comment: @Null - True. Worthy of a downvote, but not a delete vote.

Comment: @Null If I understand correctly, an attempt at an answer, even if factually wrong, is still an answer. Which means something isn't an answer only if it doesn't attempt to answer at all (e.g. if I were to post something about Dumbledore when this question doesn't even mention him)?

Comment: @Clockwork Correct. The proper course of action for this post is to downvote (if you so desire), not flag it as "not an answer".

Comment: @Null - I could be wrong, but the way I interpret the question, it's really asking what the first names were. Admittedly, the question doesn't explicitly state that, but it's hard to believe that the OP didn't already know that the surnames would be Granger. So it follows that he or she would only be asking about the parts of the names that they weren't already familiar with.

Comment: @LogicDictates Yes, the question is looking for the first names but, as the accepted answer has stated, their first names are never given. So they are just Mr./Mrs./(possibly) Dr. Granger. This answer, like the accepted one, is saying "we don't know", which is a valid answer.

Comment: @Null - This answer didn't clarify that we don't know the first names. You've now edited it to imply that, but that wasn't the thrust of the answer prior to our edits. The apparent intent of this answer was purely to clarify the proper titles.

Comment: @LogicDictates The original text stated "People are stating that they are just known as Mr. and Mrs.Granger but no. They should be presented as DR.Granger for both of them." That's an agreement that the first names are not known "they are just known as" Mr./Mrs. Granger. I have not changed the meaning of the answer, merely removed the noise about what other people are saying on this site.

Comment: @Null - It's unclear whether they were agreeing with the "just" part. They obviously weren't agreeing with the prior statement overall, and the focus of that answer was very much on the proper titles to be used, rather than what the first names were, or whether the first names were known or not.