# Does Scootaloo have biological parents or is she adopted?

Tags: my-little-pony, my-little-pony-fim

In a scene at Scootaloo's house, her parents do not make an appearance. However, Sweetie Belle and Apple Bloom both have had parents which are shown in multiple episodes. Why don't we ever see Scootaloo's parents? Does she have biological parents or other family? Is this partly why Scootaloo desires to have a sister or someone to look up to?

Comment: See http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/16754/4918 for Word of God that Hermione's family is deliberately kept in the background because we see so much of the families of the other two.

Comment: @b_jonas: I think you may have posted that comment on the wrong question. This question has absolutely nothing to do with Harry Potter.

Comment: @Martha: I've posted it for the right question. People have thought about this question hard, before and after S5 E18. They found statements about why Scootaloo can't fly and why we don't see Apple Bloom's parents, both in interviews by people involved in the show, but not in a canonical context, only as an explanation for how the character designs came about. They found nothing relevant about Scootaloo's parents.

Comment: @Martha: We probably won't get a canonical answer, so we can only speculate. In that case, JKR's statement about Hermione is at least a little bit of evidence about how some authors think about showing parents in fiction.

Answer (score 8):

The only thing we know on this topic, right now, is from an interview with Lauren Faust. It has never been addressed in the show.

> "My thoughts on Scootaloo--is that she's got parents, they're great people, we just don't...meet them. We hang out with Scootaloo when she's hanging out with her friends--and if there was ever a reason to introduce her parents in any kind of short story that we wanted to tell, then we would. [...] We [also] wanted to keep the flexibility so that if we came up with a story where Scootaloo's parents needed to be different, or she needed to have only one parent or she had foster parents...if there was a reason to give her different parents besides what I've had back in my head, we could. Because we never bothered to define it."

From Equestria L.A. 2015 [ref](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rAfyX17yA-E)

Comment: Just worth to add that for people not knowing (like anypony reading this question wouldn't) that Lauren isn't any longer working on the show, so any plan she had for the show may have been changed after she left (take for example the original intention of having only two alicorns...). Also she seem to have changed her plans about Scoots multiple times (on her deviant page she once said "she just haven't yet understood how to fly", yet later she also talked about a plan for a 3 part story involving some form of disability Scootaloo was supposed to have).

Comment: It may not be a case that she started the actual response with "For Scootaloo, *I haven’t had* a specific backstory for her at all" and concluded with something like "*This were my though, I don’t know what they do now*". We don't know if the current staff is acknowledging anyway the common fandom idea of Scoot begin orphan, the only thing we can say is that the episodes we got so far aren't really proving nothing (absence of evidence isn't evidence of absence). That said, until new information are given, this reply here is the only factual answer we can give. Kudos to you.

Answer (score 3):

Years later, Scootaloo parents make their debut in the show, during episode [S09E12 - The Last Crusade](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/The_Last_Crusade).

Coincidentally, the episodes manages to be coherent to Lauren initial vision referenced in [guildsbounty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/121159/53529) answer.

> "My thoughts on Scootaloo--is that she's got parents, they're great people, we just don't...meet them. We hang out with Scootaloo when she's hanging out with her friends--and if there was ever a reason to introduce her parents in any kind of short story that we wanted to tell, then we would."

> According to the chapter book [Riddle of the Rusty Horseshoe](https://mlp.fandom.com/wiki/Ponyville_Mysteries:_Riddle_of_the_Rusty_Horseshoe) Scootaloo lives with her two aunts Aunt Holiday and Auntie Lofty because her parents do indeed have some "demanding job" that hold them away most of the time.
>  During the season nine episode it is then revealed that her parents - Snap Shutter and Mane Allgood - are actually two world travelers who study exotic plants and creatures for medical research purposes. It is also worth noticing that the same episode also feature an appearance of Scootaloo two aunts in the show, in a way enforcing the canonicity of the chapter book.